# How to print data into a cell in an excel sheet using SAS

Tags: sas

I have data in an excel sheet but I want to add headding to each and every column.
I couldn't get how to write data into a specified cell in SAS.
Can anyone help me with this?
Like how to write data into A1, B1, C1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*SAVE YOUR EXCEL AS CSV FIRST*/
/*SAY YOU HAVE 3 COLUMNS*/
/*THEN WRITE THIS CODE*/
data CHECK_IT_OUT;
        INFILE "PATH\FILENAME.csv" 
        MISSOVER DSD;

            informat VAR1 $9. ;
            informat VAR2 anydtdte. ;
            informat VAR3 $6.;

            FORMAT VAR1 $9. ;
            FORMAT VAR2 MMDDYY10. ;
            FORMAT VAR3 $6. ;
             input
             VAR1 $
             VAR2
             VAR3 $
            ;
    run;
```

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: I am new to SAS. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Hey,                                                                                                             1. "INFILE" is use to input csv files.                                                              2. INFILE with path (from where the csv file is) and FILENAME (it is the filename of the csv file). Basically infile with Path and file name is telling sas to import/pick the csv file from the path which we are specifying.

Comment: 3. "informat" here is used to tell  how raw data should be read. if a column character and of length 9 we can give it some name with $ sign and length 4. "format" is similar to informat but it just differs in sense that it tells SAS how to show the output  instead of input as in the case of "informat"